# How to compare datetime and get first and last date MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have below mentioned tables: MySQL Version - 5.7.25

Table1:

```
ID             ref
T-1            abc-1-x
T-2            abc-2-x
T-3            abc-3-x
T-4            abc-4-x
T-5            abc-5-x
```

Table2

```
ref_id        value          date
abc-1-x       250            2019-12-10 14:16:19
abc-2-x       500            2019-12-11 17:21:05
abc-3-x       100            2019-12-12 18:11:01
abc-4-x       150            2019-12-13 05:04:11
abc-5-x       120            2019-12-14 12:10:09
```

Table3

```
ID           seq             date2
T-1          1               2019-12-10 14:05:04
T-1          2               2019-12-10 21:17:01
T-1          3               2019-12-11 13:12:12
T-2          1               2019-12-11 14:13:46
T-2          2               2019-12-12 14:05:04
T-3          1               2019-12-12 14:05:04
T-3          2               2019-12-12 17:15:14
T-3          3               2019-12-13 10:09:08
T-3          4               2019-12-14 12:18:14
T-4          1               2019-12-13 01:01:04
T-4          2               2019-12-13 03:03:01
T-5          1               2019-12-15 14:05:04
```

By utilizing the above mentioned three tables, I want to compare the `date` of Table2 with Table3 against each `ID`, and fetch the first date and last date from Table3 against each id.

Scenarios:

- If any date of Table3 less than against particular id in Table2 show it as `Less`
- If any date of Table3 equal to against particular id in Table2 show it as `Same`
- If any date of Table3 greater than against particular id in Table2 show it as `Greater`

Required Output:

```
ID          Value     date                  date1                 date2                remarks   day_diff
T-1         250       2019-12-10 14:16:19   2019-12-10 14:05:04   2019-12-11 13:12:12  Greater   1
T-2         500       2019-12-11 17:21:05   2019-12-11 14:13:46   2019-12-12 14:05:04  Greater   1
T-3         100       2019-12-12 18:11:01   2019-12-12 14:05:04   2019-12-14 12:18:14  Greater   2
T-4         150       2019-12-13 05:04:11   2019-12-13 01:01:04   2019-12-13 03:03:01  Same      0
T-5         120       2019-12-14 12:10:09   2019-12-15 14:05:04   Null                 Greater   1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a subquery to generate the `MAX` and `MIN` dates from `Table3` for each entry in `Table2` and then generate the `Greater/Same/Less` values in an outer query:

```
SELECT *, 
       CASE WHEN DATE(date2) > DATE(date) OR DATE(date1) > DATE(date) THEN 'Greater'
            WHEN DATE(date2) < DATE(date) OR DATE(date1) < DATE(date) THEN 'Less'
            ELSE 'Same'
       END AS remarks,
       DATEDIFF(date2, date) AS day_diff
FROM (
  SELECT t3.ID, t2.Value, t2.date, MIN(t3.date2) AS date1, MAX(t3.date2) AS date2
  FROM Table1 t1
  JOIN Table2 t2 ON t2.ref_id = t1.ref
  JOIN Table3 t3 ON t3.ID = t1.ID
  GROUP BY t3.ID, t2.Value, t2.date
) g
```

Output:

```
ID      Value   date                    date1                   date2                   remarks    day_diff
T-1     250     2019-12-10 14:16:19     2019-12-10 14:05:04     2019-12-11 13:12:12     Greater    1
T-2     500     2019-12-11 17:21:05     2019-12-11 14:13:46     2019-12-12 14:05:04     Greater    1
T-3     100     2019-12-12 18:11:01     2019-12-12 14:05:04     2019-12-14 12:18:14     Greater    2
T-4     150     2019-12-13 05:04:11     2019-12-13 01:01:04     2019-12-13 03:03:01     Same       0
T-5     120     2019-12-14 12:10:09     2019-12-15 14:05:04     2019-12-15 14:05:04     Greater    1
```

Note that if there is only one date for a `Table2` value in `Table3`, this will give the same values for `date1` and `date2`. If you really want `NULL` for `date2` in that case, change the `SELECT *` in the above query to

```
SELECT ID, Value, date, date1,
       CASE WHEN date1 = date2 THEN NULL ELSE date2 END AS date2,
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=cfaf508684ae3f23b08d021e8fc7e29a)

Comment: Thank, How can I get `day_diff`. From Date2 to Date.

Comment: @VectorJX apologies - it was too far off to the right and I missed it. I've updated the query and demo to include it.